# Find stored proc's dependent elements in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have add a parameter to an existing oracle stored proc. Is there a simple way to find other stored proc that would have to be modified?

I'm using Oracle SQL Developper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` (or `ALL_DEPENDENCIES` or `USER_DEPENDENCIES`) directly to get that information

```
SELECT owner,
       name,
       type
  FROM all_dependencies
 WHERE referenced_owner = <<owner of procedure>>
   AND referenced_name  = <<name of procedure>>
```

In SQL Developer, you can also pull up the procedure and click the "References" tab to get a list of the objects that reference the procedure.